# matlab: cannot import package

Tags: matlab, import, package

Probably a basic mistake, but the cause is eluding me. I am trying to import a package, but I get an error saying it cannot be found or imported.

First I set the current directory to the parent directory of the package, and this does not work.

Second, the docs say that the parent folder of the package must be added to the matlab path. I tried this, and still no luck.

[image]

It is not due to using `plot` as the package name as I get the same error when trying to import `analysis`.

What I can do is to import using: `import plot.*` or `import analyse.*` and then go on to use the functions in the packages, but I want to use the namespaces (i.e. not use `.*`).

**Edit**
I'm having this problem on both versions I have installed: 2015b and 2016a.

Comment: Post a link to the package? With regards to your use of `addpath` (a) it will only be for the current session. Use `savepath` to make it permanent and (b) it won't include subfolders, use `genpath` for that like this `addpath(genpath(pwd))` ([from the `addpath` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html))

Comment: link to minimum working example... https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n2lc52s0kf6ktpv/AABZ6cVgeVF3JfafLjKmU5m4a?dl=0

Comment: but how do you want to use it? I ask because you could also just make it like a toolbox i.e. leave off the `+` in the folder names and use the `addpath(genpath...` syntax depending on your usecase

Comment: I was hoping to use packages to keep things modular in a set of analysis tools that I am working on across multiple github repos etc. Sure I could carry on using `addpath` like I am now, but that is a separate matter of approach. What I'm focussing on here is actually getting the seemingly simple task of importing to work.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, I still don't think you need to use `import` unless you only want to get part of you package into your path. From [these docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) I think your current `addpath(pwd)` should work and you should be able to use `analyse.testFunc`. The docs state *All references to packages, functions, and classes in the package must use the package name prefix,* ***unless you import*** *the package.*

Comment: Ok. It looks like this is caused by my preconception that you should import a package in order to use it. I think their docs could make different use cases a little clearer. I can indeed just type: addpath(pwd), analyse.testFunc()

Comment: At the bottom right of the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) there is a "was this helpful" section, click no and you can write to them to explain what your confusion was. It's the one advantage of MATLAB being proprietary, they do respond to feedback about the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that, somewhat counterintuitively, you don't need to call `import` at all. [The docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) state that

> The parent of the top-level package folder must be on the MATLAB path.

Which is what your `addpath(pwd)` does and then state that (emphasis is mine):

> All references to packages, functions, and classes in the package must
>   use the package name prefix, **unless you import the package**.

Meaning at this stage you should be able to call

```
analyse.testFunc
```

If you were to `import analyse.testFunc` you would then be able to call `testFunc` without prefacing it with the namespace but since you want to retain the namespace the answer is to not call `import` at all.

Comment: Thanks. This also provides access to sub packages with `mypackage.subpackage.myfunction()`, so no need for `genpath` if taking this approach it seems